# Autocompletion in CJK languages is failing in QtWebEngine View (qml) using the QtVirtualKeyBoard

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qml

I have a qml based webbrowser that I am using in Qt 5.12 where inputboxes in a webform (for example the search in google) fail to autocomplete for CJK languages when using the QtVirtualKeyboard.    Normal QtTextBoxes work fine it is only when trying to use an input box in the QtWebEngineView that the autocompletion does not work as expected.   Has anyone else experienced this?   Does anyone know a fix if you have?